# Rails passing params to different model and then saving it not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a '**post**' controller in that I have two variable title and body which I am passing through strong parameters.But I need to use two other variable which are path and name which are in different model name '**Document**'..And also I am saving the content in database ..but unable to do so..getting this error view [posts/_form.html.erb]
**undefined method `name' for #**

[posts_controller]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 

    def index
        @posts = Post.user_post(current_user).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)

    end 

    def new
        @post = Post.new

    end

    def show
        @post = find_params
    end

    def create

        @post = Post.create(post_params)

        @post.user = current_user


        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = find_params
    end

    def update
        @post = find_params

        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = find_params
        @post.destroy

        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private

    def post_params

        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
        Document.new(params,:files=>[])
    end

    def find_params
        Post.find(params[:id])
    end


end
```

[post/_form.html.erb]

```
<%= form_for @post,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>
    <br>
        <%= f.label :name %> <br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <%= f.label :path %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :path %><br>


    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[document.rb]

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :path, presence: true
    validates :resource_type, presence: true
    validates :resource_id, presence: true

    mount_uploader :path, PathUploader 
    validates :name, presence: true 

    # def self.abc
    #   params.permit(:name,:path)
    # end
    def initialize(params,file)
        params=file[:name]  
        #params.permit(name =>:name,path =>:path)

    end

end
```

Comment: `params=file[:name]` overwrites all your form values

Comment: ok so how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to specify an association. Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You may want to go through Hartl's Rails tutorial first before you get in too deep. https://www.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `name' for #

You're referencing a *non-existent attributes* for your `Post` form:

```
<%= form_for @post,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Remove `:name` & `:path` references.

--

If you want to pass "extra" attributes to another model, you need to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) *or* set the params separately to your "primary" model:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :documents
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end

#app/models/document.rb
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end
```

This will allow you to pass the `documents` as "nested" attributes of your `Post` model:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @post = Post.new
      @post.documents.build
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.new post_params
      @post.save
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, documents_attributes: [:name, :path])
   end
end

#app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area  :body  %>
  <%= f.fields_for :documents do |d| %>
     <%= d.text_field :name %>
     <%= d.text_field :path %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Okay dude, thanks for telling me; you should either close this question or mark the other answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

So `undefined method` on a model will indicate that, well, the method doesn't exist on the model. Want to see a model's methods? `Post.methods`. However, in this example, the column `name` is not defined on the model., and you're trying to tell `Post` that it has a `name`. What you need to do is `nest` your parameters.

While there is a ton of cleaning up that might want to focus on first, your answer is found in the `accepts_nestable_attributes_for` class methods, as shown here, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, and strong_params documentation as shown here, http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

In your case, you want to create a new document from a post. Your permitted params hash will look like this,

`params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :document_attributes => [:name])`

Ensure that document_attributes is singular; if a person has_many pets (for example), then you'd have pets_attributes.

In your form, something that often trips people up is the builder.

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.text_field :body %>

<%= f.fields_for @post.document do |document_field| %>
<%= document_field.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Make sure that you're telling ERB that `<%= f.fields_for %>`, not just `<% f.fields_for %>`.